# Installation issue

Tags: permissions

So I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my windows 7 system with more than enough power to run this operating system. When the installer is finished instead of "congrats, enjoy your new operating system", I get something cryptic.

An error occured

Permission denied

For more info please see the log file

c:\users\megan\appdata\local\temp\wubi......

but I don't have an appdata folder. After the installation failed the first time I started wubi.exe as an admin but I still get the permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

The log file probably exists, the log is just in a hidden windows folder.

In windows Control Panel > Folders, there is an option to show hidden folders.

Once you are able to view the log file, it should give an indication of what's wrong.

Many users experience problems with Wubi. You may have more success installing the old-fashioned way, by rebooting your computer and having your BIOS boot directly to the CD/DVD.